# Using Redirection in New Action in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to construct my first new action in rails, thanks to the help of people here I have now got the vast majority working, but due to my mis-understanding of exactly how things work the  action is not performing the desired action.

I have a database called `Items`, which contains `:id`, `:external_url` and `:click_count`
My goal is to have a link which when clicked on, the user is directed to the external url and `:click_count` is incremented by 1.

As it stands, I have the following:
`view`

```
<%= link_to image_tag( item.picture.to_s + ".gif"), items_clickcountplusone_path(:id => item.id)%>
```

`items_controller`

```
def clickcountplusone
    clickeditem = Item.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to clickeditem.external_url if clickeditem.update_attribute(:click_count, clickeditem.click_count + 1)
end
```

`routes.rb`

```
get 'items/:id' => 'items#clickcountplusone', :as => :items_clickcountplusone
```

Using this code, the page itself loads with all the links visible.
However, when I click on a link I get directed to `items/whateveridiclickedon` NOT the external URL and furthermore the `:click_count` value does not increase from its initial value.

Am I doing this correctly?  In particular is the routes line ok, it currently appears as though i am instructing it to be directed to a specific page on my site for the item, which was not my intention... Also, what is wrong with the `if` statement meaning the count doesn't increase?

Many thanks for your patience

Comment: Try this? `<%= link_to image_tag( item.picture.to_s + ".gif"), items_clickcountplusone_path(:id => item.id) %>`

Comment: I actually had it like that already - I just deleted it by accident as i put it on there (I was deleting an alt description and must have deleted too much). But thanks for checking so closely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapped route `"items/:id"` is already associated with the `show` action and have precedence.

Try associating it with another URL.

```
get 'items/:id/visit' => 'items#visit', :as => :items_visit
```